# Is there a way to make text, buttons, progress bar stay in around the same area with any resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imagebutton, android-xml

Is there a way to make text, buttons, progress bar stay in around the same area with any resolution. So if you on a nexus 10 and nexus 7 the text, buttons, progress bar will say around the same place. As my app just looks silly on nexus 10. Heres my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textSize="20dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pauseicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/pauseicon" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that you write your layout like you have. To make your app look similar on different devices, you should align all the views so that they are relational to each other.

There is a lot of information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

I would also advise that you use a [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) rather than a linear layout, because it is easier to make the views relational to each other, which (usually) makes your app look better at different screen sizes.

Here is an example of a relative layout(from the dev docs)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/reminder" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dates"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@id/times"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/times"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/done" />
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @user2407147 - done - you should change your layout to include more alignParent.... and toLeft/RightOf.... It is a little annoying and means that you cant always design layouts just like you want them, but to support multiple screen sizes it is a nessecity